# I'm trying to allow only parts of a div to be editable with contenteditable and some not

Tags: reactjs

I have a div that allows the user to enter text into. Inside of that I also have divs that cannot be edited. These non editable divs will be dynamically created when the page is loaded. The end goal is to have these non editable divs contain text and then allow the user to write more text under or above it (sort of like the game madlib but with phrases not just words)

```
<div
      contenteditable="true"
      style={{
        margin: "auto",
        width: "90%",
        height: "90%",
        overflow: "scroll",
      }}
    >
      This text should be editable
      <div
        contenteditable="false"
        style={{
          margin: 2,
          borderRadius: 10,
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: "Red",
        }}
      >
        {" "}
        THIS CODE IS NOT EDITABLE
      </div>
      This text should be editable
      <div
        contenteditable="false"
        style={{
          margin: 2,
          borderRadius: 10,
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: "Red",
        }}
      >
        {" "}
        THIS CODE IS NOT EDITABLE
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I have right now to test the non editable and editable text. The issue though is the user can backspace or use the delete key and delete the divs that shouldn't be editable. This isn't what I want to happen.

I'm using Reactjs and my editor is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You could just put another div above and below the non-editable div and make that contenteditable?

Comment: I tried that and that solved the issue but I also needed to allow the user to select the whole document. By doing it that way the user can't select their entered text and the text that can't be edited